# Receive authentication response data from a non-Google service via a Gmail add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm building a Gmail add-on with 2 steps:

1. Authorization with Gmail account.
2. Authenticate to access my service.

Example: The same as Trello add-on:

[image: trello]

When I click the button to login, a login form appears like this:

[image: example]

I want to receive data response after sign-in. I've read [`ActionResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action-response) documentation, but can not find a solution.

How can I receive the data response?

Answer (score 1):

I believe , you are trying to authorize a custom service.
In order to authorize a custom service like trello, you will have to configure oAuth for it.

Create an oAuth service at gmail add-on to request access to trello.
Once the user completes the oAuth flow, you can use the oAuth service to get the access token. Use this token to access the endpoints whenever required.

Refer [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services)

Edit 1:

**Action Response** 
The usage is as follows:

```html
    //action
    var onTestBtnClick = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('onTestBtnClick');
    //Button
    var testBtn = CardService.newTextButton().setText('test').setOnClickAction(onTestBtnClick);
    //action handler
    function onTestBtnClick(){
        //do some action and finally open google.com
        return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
            .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
            .setUrl("https://www.google.com"))
        .build();
    }
```

Comment: I authorized before, then i used email and password for authenticattion to access trello. If you try to use Trello add-on, you can see.

Comment: May I know what would you like to see in the response ?

Comment: Trello add-on is an only example. I have my service, i authenticate with email and password to use api. The response which i'll receive: user_id, status,etc ..

Comment: I was trying to view the response , but the window closes as soon I authenticate. Can you share it here ?

Comment: @phambaonam I've added ActionResponse usage to the answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello. I have the same issue. I'd like to authenticate to use my API with e-mail and password in external window, but without oAuth with Google. I didn't catch from your response how to do that.

Comment: @Niko , what kind of authorization for your API are you using ? I tried to authorize without oauth initially . I couldn't send a response to the gmail addon from another window without using a oauth flow. Thus I configure my app to use with oauth.

Comment: @HariBalaji So do you say that if I want to authenticate to my services I need to support oAuth?

Comment: How is the "Login with trello" achieved, that it opens a trello login page in separate window, and you authenticate with trello login and password, not your google account?

Comment: Since Trello had already done that , it is evident that the even without oauth , we can authorize.

Comment: It is possible to open a login page of trello with a button click . However I could not find a way to redirect the response of the login to the gmail addon . That's why I went with oauth.

Comment: @HariBalaji, thanks for your answer. good luck with development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174245/discussion-between-hari-balaji-and-niko).

Comment: Hi again. Have you found any solution to receive callback from another window?

Comment: Hi Niko. Haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a separate authentication page for your server(3rd party service). The user has to go through the auth process on your page. Once the user successfully authenticates with your page you need to redirect him to the `redirect_uri` which is passed to your page from the add-on as an url parameter. Script at the `redirect_uri` will hit your token url endpoint, which you specify when initiating add-ons auth service. If your token url endpoint returns a valid response, `authcallback` function in your add-on code is triggered which caches the session and lets the user proceed with using your add-on.

Here's a diagram of the overall flow:

[image]

Check out [this library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) Google provides to make the implementation easier.

Also checkout [my post](https://isamatov.com/implement-gmail-add-on-authentication/) which goes into more detail on how to connect your 3rd party services to Gmail add-on

Answer (score 0):

Please see this documentation https://isamatov.com/gmail-add-on-connect-non-google-service/

This will provide you the your ans.

You need to the login page url in

```
setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://domain/login.php')
```

The response which you want to receive is need to set in below URL

```
 setTokenUrl('https://domain/response.php')

function getService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Demo Auth')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://domain/json.php')
    .setTokenUrl('https://domain/token.php')
 }
```